# Laravel $dateformat is working in one-way

Tags: sql-server, laravel, php-carbon

Normal format of a timestamp is `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, but I am using SQL Server and its datetime format is `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v'`, i.e '2020-06-28T03:59:51.142'

I've already used in my models

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v';
```

this works well on method `create()`, but fails on `save()`

It throws an exception:

```
Carbon/Exceptions/InvalidFormatException with message 'Unexpected data found.'
```

How can I make it work in both ways?

---

### My Code

#### My model:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v';

    protected $fillable = [
        'question',
        'right',
        'wrongs',
        'times_played',
        'times_right',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'wrongs' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

#### Example of create():

```
Question::create(["question" => "Most popular Web Search Engine?", "right" => "Google", "wrongs" => ['Yahoo', 'Bing', 'Yandex']]);

App\Question {#3965
     question: "Most popular Web Search Engine?",
     right: "Google",
     wrongs: "['Yahoo','Bing','Yandex']",
     updated_at: "2020-06-28T19:17:49.923", // Look these formats, seems OK
     created_at: "2020-06-28T19:17:49.923",
     id: 9,
   }
```

#### Now, find and save:

```
$q = App\Question::find(9)

App\Question {#4030
     id: "9",
     question: "Most popular Web Search Engine?",
     right: "Google",
     wrongs: "['Yahoo','Bing','Yandex']",
     image: null,
     upvotes: "0",
     downvotes: "0",
     times_right: "0",
     times_played: "0",
     created_at: "2020-06-28 19:17:49.923", // These formats are not
     updated_at: "2020-06-28 19:17:49.923",
     deleted_at: null,
   }

$q->upvotes = 10;
$q->save();
Carbon/Exceptions/InvalidFormatException with message 'Unexpected data found.'
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create() vs how you save()

Comment: Carbon cant pharse your date in this format `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v`

Comment: Carbon perfectly can parse it: `Carbon::parse('2020-06-07T20:00:00.999')` if there is an issue, it's Laravel-side, or app-side, not Carbon-side.

Comment: Is the fields in the `protected $dates` of your model?

Comment: I've already added my code. I believe there is no need to use `protected $dates`, as those dates are defaults timestamps `created_at` and `updated_at`

Answer (score 0):

`save()` you didn't convert date to `Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v`. You define format in model is used if you use `create()`. For `save()` you want to format using carbon.

Answer (score 0):

After looking for a solution, and trying different things (i.e. `protected $dateFormat`  and `public function fromDateTime($value)` in models), finally I solved it only by changing migrations:

**From**

```
$table->timestamps();
```

**To**

```
$table->timestamps(2);
```